# How to count the number of FLOPs needed to solve linear equation using FFT algorithm.

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I would like to solve a linear equation

**Cx=b**

where **C** is a circulant square matrix with size n*x*n. By applying the circular convolution theorem, **discrete Fourier Transform** can be used to transform the cyclic convolution into component-wise multiplication  written as

$ F_n(\textbf{c} \star \textbf{x}) = F_n(\textbf{c})F_n(\textbf{x}) = F_n(\textbf{b}) $

so that

$x = F_n^{-1}\bigg[\bigg( \frac{(F_n(\textbf{b}))_v)}{(F_n(\textbf{c}))_v}\bigg)_{v\in\textbf{Z}}\bigg]^T$ .

My question is how many number of FLOPs needed to calculate a vector **x**?

Comment: I suppose that you just need to calculate the exact number of operations in terms of $n$. Then the answer will depend on CPU

Comment: I need to analyse in terms of n. What I know is FFT algorithm has O(N log N) of FLOPs. However, in my case, I have used one time of  IFFT and 2 times of FFT. Therefore, what is the total amount of FLOPs should be?